# Extending gezeirot about melacha to other activities

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, derabanan

I feel like this is too obvious even to ask (or that it is a dupe...) but here goes:

If we do not use already ground medicine on Shabbos for fear that we [might](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tochen#cite_note-39) come to [grind](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Medicine_on_Shabbat#cite_ref-2) medicine, then why can we use already ground salt and pepper on our food (assuming we can) even though each of those is ground up before use as well? Isn't it possible that we might come to grind more for the need?

The same holds true of other activities -- if we can't use a musical instrument for fear of [makeh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55420/1362) b'patish, why can we use a chair which might also need repair to be immediately useful? If we can't blow the shofar, shake the arba minim or read megillah for fear of [carrying](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/reading-megillah-purim-morning/) each, why do we read from the Torah, which also might have to be carried?

Comment: I thought, the whole idea of Gzerot that they weren't systematic and completely reasonable. Instead, they were very specific with no ability to derive any further tendencies. If you look at the Gemmorah, those rulings weren't preceded by extensive discussions and arguments, there were just issued. So that's how we should treat them - as single, specific rulings.

Comment: Short answer -- human psychology is weird, and Chazal planned accordingly. Medicines vs. spices -- people panic about their health and do things they otherwise wouldn't. Carrying a special-holiday item -- people get so caught up in the special holiday, they forget about shabbos -- vs. a sefer torah which is standard every week.

Comment: @AlBerko then my question would be "why didn't chazal make other case specific gezeirot on equivalent or parallel activities?"

Comment: @Shalom that seems to be a psychologically based, post hoc rationalizing. If that's what it is, then so be it. I was just wondering if there was some intended distinction which could help explain.

Comment: @rosends not at all post hoc! Learn meseches Shabbos -- *adum bahul al gufo*.

Comment: @Shalom my mistake -- I meant ad hoc.